# Set div value of WebElement with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I want to set new value of div element by using Selenium `FirefoxDriver` in Java:

```
<div my-div-name="lastname">
  <p>Smith</p>
</div>
```

I have successfully retrieved the div element (as `WebElement`) by use of XPATH expression and have also been able to get current value `Smith` by use of `getText()` method. However, there is no `setText()` method of an `WebElement`. So I have in stead tried to execute JavaScript:

```
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].value = 'Foo Bar'", element);
```

but nothing happens. New `getText()` call still returns `Smith`.

Any tip on how to set the value successfully?

Comment: What is the purpose of directly setting the value here? How would a user change this value?

Comment: Good question, JeffC! Im not using WebDriver for test purpose, but for creation of 400 new pages. This approach is used as lack of remote APIs for the web portal solution.

Comment: ??? If you change values using Selenium they aren't saved. As soon as you reload the page, the changes go away. I'm still confused as to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: JeffC, take it easy. Im sure this solves my requirements as I have tested it already and it does work. HTML being modified is within WYSIWYG editor which saves HTML when submit button is hit. So no worries. But you are correct that in general scenario editing HTML in a page is not persistent.

Comment: Just to be clear, I wasn't getting excited. :) I was just confused as to what you were trying to do. It makes more sense now that you mentioned that it was an editor in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution** is to set `innerHTML` property like this:

```
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = arguments[1]", element, text);
```

I have tried to do this several times, but i wrote `innerHtml` and not `innerHTML` so be aware of casing when setting the property.